# Sharing a model between two views

Tags: eclipse, model, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am still learning how to use rich client platform and window builder.

what I have at the moment is a simple plugin project with a view, I then added a second view and in the perspetiveextensions extension, I made it so that both of the views are side by side...

But now here is the question, I have this model provider:

```
public enum ModelProvider {
    INSTANCE;

    List<Object> model;

    private ModelProvider {
        model = new ArayList<Object>();

        //make some objects here
        //add the objects to the list
    }

    public List<Object> getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

the thing is that I want to share this model with both of the views, because if I go and write this:
`ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getModel()`
and assign it to some list within each of the views, then surely they will have their own copy of the model and I would like it to be shared...

how can I initialise my application in such a way that it both of my views can share the same model...

perhaps in Application.java??

sorry this is really new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, you are using the singleton design pattern.

The reference leading to the `List< Object >` would firstly need to be private, to prevent any sort of outside access.

This way, without a setter or any other way to access and change the model variable, if you access `ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getModel()` you will receive the same `ArrayList< Object>`. 
The Eclipse OSGI Equinox framework does not alter the expected behavior of singletons

- If both views are in the SAME plugin, alongside with the ModelProvider, the plug-in initialization will not be important.
- If the views are in different plugins, that means that the plug-in that the ModelProvider is, should either be added in MANIFEST.MF file via `Require-Bundle` directive, or the package where the ModelProvider is, to be added via the `Import-Package` directive in the plug-ins that contain the views

I will edit my answer depending on the scenario you're talking about